# Change accessibility traversal order in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I have a layout with two AutoCompleteTextViews, when I type in upper AutoCompleteTextView, a popup window of suggestions is shown and it will hide the lower AutoCompleteTextViews. This has no problem until I enable Talkback. When talkback is enabled, accessibility will traverse the lower (hidden) AutoCompleteTextView before traversing the suggestions. Does anyone know how I can change the traversal order here so that talkback will announce the suggestions before announcing the hidden AutoCompleteTextView?

[image]
[image: after]

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Autocomplete Demo"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.158" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
    android:ems="10"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.126"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,UnknownId" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
    android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@android:id/text1"
    android:ems="10"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.027"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,UnknownId" />
```

Comment: Seems like this question does not have answer at the moment. The suggestions are shown in a popupWindow and Accessbility does not support rearranging traversal order between different windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is still not fixed for `AutoCompleteTextView` (regular and AppCompat), but it works properly if you use `com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` instead.

Focus will lock in to the PopupWindow and cycle through the array of dropdown items.